# Django creating a custom list_filter

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I want to create a custom list_filter on `AvariaAdmin`, to check if `env_emp` is empty or not , i dont know how to do that

**My MODELS**

```html
class Avaria(models.Model):
    .......
```

```html
class Pavimentacao(models.Model):

    avaria = models.ForeignKey(Avaria, related_name='AvariaObjects',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    env_emp= models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `admin.py` file, register the Avaria model with something like this:

```py
class EmptyDateFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('empty date')
    parameter_name = 'env_emp'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('all', 'All'),
            ('has_no_date', 'Has no date')
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        value = self.value()
        if value == 'all':
           return queryset
        isnull = (value == "has_no_date")
        return queryset.filter(AvariaObjects__env_emp__isnull=isnull)

@admin.register(Avaria)
class AvariaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (EmptyDateFilter, )
```

You can find more information on the [list_filter documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/)

Comment: yeh , it is working, but it only shows when it is filled, I want to always show and just make the filter after I fill it

Comment: basically I just want to make the filter after I select it, if it does not select anything, it does not filter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull) field lookup to check if a nullable field is empty:

```
Pavimentacao.objects.filter(env_emp__isnull=True)
```